# fat models and thin controllers in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

this is a user.php controller

```
public function verifyLogin() {
    if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
        $e = $this->input->post("email");
        $p = $this->input->post("pass");

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "email", "required|valid_email|xss_clean");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("pass", "password", "required|xss_clean");

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data = array(
                'select' => '*',
                'table' => 'users',
                'where' => "email = '$e' AND activated = '1'"
            );
            $checklogin = $this->query2->selectData($data);
            if ($checklogin === FALSE) {
                echo "quering userInfo fails. email is wrong or activation not done";
                exit();
            } else {
                foreach ($checklogin as $row) {
                    $dbid = $row->id;
                    $dbusername = $row->username;
                    $dbpassword = $row->password;
                    $dbemail = $row->email;
                    if ($p === $dbpassword) {
                        $login_data = array(
                            'name' => $dbusername,
                            'email' => $dbemail,
                            'password' => $dbpassword,
                            'id' => $dbid,
                            'expire' => '86500',
                            'secure' => TRUE,
                            'logged_in' => TRUE
                        );
                        $this->input->set_cookie($login_data);
                        $this->session->set_userdata($login_data);
                        if ($this->session->userdata("logged_in")) {
                            $time = time();
                            $now = unix_to_human($time, TRUE, 'us');
                            $updateLogin = $this->query1->updateLogin($e, $now);
                            if ($updateLogin) {
                                echo "success";
                            } else {
                                echo 'update failed';
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "session failed";
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo 'password incorrect';
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "form validation fails";
        }
    } else {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('login');
        $this->load->view('modal');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

this is model.php

```
public function selectData($data){

    if(isset($data['direction'])){
        $dir = $data['direction'];
    }else{
        $dir = "ASC";
    }

    if(isset($data['offset'])){
        $off = $data['offset'];
    }else{
        $off = '0';
    }

    if(isset($data['select']) && isset($data['table'])){
        $this->db->select($data['select'])->from($data['table']);
    }

    if(isset($data['where'])){
        $this->db->where($data['where']);
    }
    if(isset($data['order_by_name'])){
        $this->db->order_by($data['order_by_name'], $dir);
    }
    if(isset($data['limit'])){
        $this->db->limit($data['limit'], $off);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query){
        $d = $query->result();
        return $d;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

is this a good way of quering database? 
i am new to mvc and i am reading everywhere about "fat models and this controllers"
what can be done to make it a good mvc architecture?

Comment: As in life, surely fat controllers and thin models are preferable?

Comment: Except echos within the controller, I don't see major mistakes. The strategy isn't the best but it's not wrong. Why don't you do multiple models and specific functions instead of one generic select function for all your db access ?

Answer (score 0):

its only acceptable to echo out from the controller when you are developing:

```
 if ($checklogin === FALSE) {
                echo "quering userInfo fails.
```

if checking login is false then either show a view or go to a new method like

```
 if ($checklogin === FALSE) { 

      $this->showLoginFailed($errorMessage) ;
```

the check login code in the controller is a great example of something that could be refactored to a model. then if you need to check login from another controller its much easier. putting the form validation code in a model would be another choice. often times when you are validating form code you are also inserting/updating to a database table -- so having all those details together in a model can make things easier long term.

**"fat model" does not mean one method in a model that does a hundred things.** it means the controller says -- did this customer form validate and insert to the database? yes or no? 3 lines of code.

the model has the code that is looking into the "fat" details of the form, validation, database, etc etc. say 50 or more lines compared to the 3 in the controller. but the methods in the model should still be clean: small and specific.

Comment: so instead of making a general selectData function i should separate them for particular use. i actually had 8 different select queries. i was using echo for development purpose only. can you explain the refactored checklogin function???